# How to programmatically change help contents in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin and I would like to programmatically disable help content TOC's based on a variable I define.  In a nut shell, I want to prevent some help docs from showing up in the help contents if a specific type of user is accessing the plugin.

Preferably I would like to do this in the ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor somewhere.

One thought would be to modify the "primary" value to be false if the variable were set.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work, but try using the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point. The tutorial from [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/) tells it is possible to hide only UI elements like wizards, views and so on, but it is from 2009.. Not sure if hiding TOC is now possible. If you try it out, would be nice to give a feedback ;)